# Executar Evento TextBox c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, eventos-do-mouse

Tenho um Textbox e preciso que após apertar o botao direito do mouse e clicar em colar, ele faça uma verificação, tentei usar varios métodos como

```
TxtTexto.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown+= new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseClick);
TxtTexto.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseClick);
TxtTexto.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseClick);
TxtTexto.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseClick);
```

Entre outros códigos, é possível capiturar esse evento? [image: Imagem do click no textbox]

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo  como isso.

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // "tb" é o seu TextBox
    DataObject.AddPastingHandler(tb, OnPaste);
}

private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    //faça suas verificações aqui use o 'e' para obter os dados presente no past.
    var isText = e.SourceDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
    if (!isText) return;

    var text = e.SourceDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText) as string;

}
```

> Referencias
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061475/paste-event-in-a-wpf-textbox

Comment: fiz o teste aqui, e não funcionou troquei o tb pelo meu textobox e nao fez nada...

Comment: No caso, ele esta colando o texto e fazendo 2 verificacoes

Comment: Mas o evento `OnPaste` é evocado? Quais verificações é que está a fazer?

Comment: sim, é evocado, no caso eu pego o texto, faço as verificações e no final eu seto o texto formatado de acordo com o que preciso